# PHP - Two JSON lists in one (two-dimensional)

Tags: php, json

I'm trying using PHP to bring the two JSON lists into one, as follows:

list1

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

list2

```
["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

How to join lists to get:

```
[[1,"a"],[2,"b"],[3,"c"],[4,"d"],[5,"e"]]
```

How to link two lists to one, as in a given example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the arrays, and create a new one with the combined values:

```
<?php

$arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$arr2 = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
$result = [];

foreach ($arr1 as $i => $a) {
    $result[]  = [$a, $arr2[$i] ?? ''];
}

?>
```